# The order of items is infuenced by the object type during the conversion from list to set

Tags: python, python-3.8

During the conversion of a list object to a set object, the order of items does not change if the list contains integers or floats. However, if the list contains strings, the order is changed.

```py
def list_set_order(x):
    print(f'x:{x}')
    print(f'set(x):{set(x)}')
    print(f'list(set(x)):{list(set(x))}')


list_set_order([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
list_set_order([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
list_set_order(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
```

What does cause this behaviour ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Order is never guaranteed to be preserved whenever you use `set()` so whether or not it's changed you should never expect such behaviour. If you share your use-case, perhaps someone can suggest a viable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may depend from the implementation of the `__hash__` method which may be "monotonic" in numeric types (if `a > b`, then `hash(a) > hash(b)`) but not in strings. However, as the other comment states, you should generally not rely upon order of items in set.

Comment: Note: if you have a set and want a list ordered in a predictable way, look at the builtin `sorted` function

Comment: The question is **why the order is preserved when the input list contains integers or floats, wherase the order is not preserved if the input list contains strings**.  The above written description does neither mention a guarante nor an expected behaviour, but refers to the impact of types.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentations:

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

So the ordering is only when displaying. The set itself is not in a particular order.